# Kafka Consumer is not receiving message in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My spring/java consumer is not able to access the message produced by producer. However, when I run the consumer from console/terminal it is able to receive the message produced by spring/java producer.

Consumer Configuration :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="kafka.consumer")
public class KafkaConsumerProperties {

    private String bootstrap;
    private String group;
    private String topic;

    public String getBootstrap() {
        return bootstrap;
    }

    public void setBootstrap(String bootstrap) {
        this.bootstrap = bootstrap;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
}
```

Listener Configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> getConsumerProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getBootstrap());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getGroup());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Deserializer stringKeyDeserializer() {
        return new StringDeserializer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Deserializer transactionJsonValueDeserializer() {
        return new JsonDeserializer(Transaction.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Transaction> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(getConsumerProperties(), stringKeyDeserializer(), transactionJsonValueDeserializer());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Transaction> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Transaction> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Kafka Listener :

```
@Service
public class TransactionConsumer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Transaction.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics={"transactions"}, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onReceive(Transaction transaction) {
        LOGGER.info("transaction = {}",transaction);
    }
}
```

Consumer Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**TEST CASE 1 : PASS**
I started my spring/java producer and run the consumer from console. When I produce message form producer my console consumer is able to access the  message.

**TEST CASE 2 : FAILED**
I started my spring/java consumer and run the producer from console. When I produce message form console producer my spring/java consumer is not able to access the  message.

**TEST CASE 3 : FAILED**
I started my spring/java consumer and run the spring/java producer. When I produce message form spring/java producer my spring/java consumer is not able to access the  message.

**Question**

1. Is there anything wrong in my consumer code ?
2. Am I missing any configuration for my kafka-listener?
3. Do I need to explicitly run the listener? (I don't think so since I can see on the terminal log connecting to topic, still I am not sure)

Comment: Could it be related to the way your testing it? Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay you are missing `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` in `Consumer Configs`

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

**auto.offset.reset**

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):

**earliest:** automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset

**latest:** automatically reset the offset to the latest offset

**none:** throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group

**anything else:** throw exception to the consumer

**Note :** `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` will work only if kafka does not have offset for that consumer group (So in you case need to add this property with new consumer group and restart the application)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the solution that you proposed, however, it did not work. I tried with all the option but no luck. Do you know how to set '--from-beginning' option (that we use in console) in Java code ?

Comment: `Do you know how to set '--from-beginning' option (that we use in console) in Java code ?` that is in my answer @Developer

Comment: I have exactly the same problem scenario. This solution have no luck to me either. Did you find any possible work around?

Comment: Try `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earlisest` (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset))